# Securly send passwords with PHP

Tags: php

Imagine the following situation:
You distribute software for websites including support (a Wordpress or Joomla! extension for example).
A person, let's call him Bob, ask you to help him with your software and sends you a username and password to login on his website. At this moment, the username and password are stored as plain text in your support database. How can you encrypt that, so that if the database is hacked nobody can read it.

It seems quite obviously that you have to do some encryption. But functions like `password_hash()` are only for one way encryption.
So how you do this?

Comment: It's impossible. If you can read it, the hacker can it too.

Comment: Send as hashed password & store in database. Compare to confront if.

Comment: Also `password_hash` uses **Hashing**. Encryption != Hashing

Comment: I know that, please read my question again. I'm not talking about passwords for login. I'm talking about the situation that a user sends me a password to login.

Comment: Modify the code to statically let you navigate the site as them. You should not be asking your users for their passwords.

Comment: `I'm not talking about passwords for login`....`I'm talking about the..password to login`. huh?

Comment: Example: A user aks me to fix a problem and gives its username and password. That username and password are know stored as plain text in my database. Is there a way to encrypt that, so if someone hack's my database it it unreadable (okay for as far it can be)

Comment: Quick answer: No.

Comment: How did the password get in the DB unhashed? Don't have users send you their passwords, just email/username/userid. Then modify the code to function as them, or change your local code base to compare against the hashed value.

Comment: if a hacker gets your db, your f***ed in so many ways, this is probably the least of your problems

Comment: You mean that you send the user a hashed password what can be set as password for a user account? Sounds like a good idea (Why didn't I think of that...)

Comment: No, this is all on your side. You remove the hashing function from your code deployment (`staging.yourdomain.com` or whereever you test) and login as them with their hashed password. Then replicate whatever behavior you need to as them.

Comment: That should be the options offcorse. But you can't always replicate the complete situation (and you definitely don't have time to do that for all you're support tickets). Would the method I described a good solution? (I know it is not 100%, but is it better that sending plain text messages with passwords)

Comment: Oops.... Thanks :D

Comment: If you can't replicate the situation then having their password isn't going to help you. The behavior should be 100% the same (it is the same system). It could be browser/network/OS. My final thoughts on this thread. **Never** get your user's password(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I think I understand what you are asking now after thinking about it for a while. If I am correct you want to store a username and password for later use. You don't want to remember it (I don't blame you) and you want it to be encrypted so that if someone gets access to your computer/files they won't be able to log into random peoples websites and create vulnerabilities in other peoples systems.

If I am correct in my assumption then what I would do is store the username and password pair in a text document and put that in an encrypted zip folder with 7-zip and secure that encrypted folder with a password that you do know and is secure.

This way you can access it at a later date and no one else can.